# ExtJS GridPanel Header Borders Disappear

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have posted this question on Sencha's forum, but haven't received any replies. So, now posting on SO:

We are using version 4.2.0 of Ext JS. We are displaying a grid panel, it has the rowediting plugin, so a user can edit rows. All columns have fixed widths, except one which has flex: 1.

We are seeing a strange behavior. The column headers look as below when the screen is first rendered:
[image]

After I click on a row, edit and hit Update, the header looks like below:
[image]

Notice how the right border in the header columns is now missing?

Inspecting the html in Chrome's Dev Tools, I found that in the first case when the borders are displayed, the first column has following css properties:

```
position: absolute
left: 0;
width: 199px;
border-right: 1px;
```

The second column has following css properties:

```
position: absolute
left: 200;
width: 299px;
border-right: 1px;
```

In the second case i.e. after editing a row, the first column has following properties:

```
position: absolute
left: 0;
width: 200px;
border-right: 1px;
```

The second column has following properties:

```
position: absolute
left: 200;
width: 300px;
border-right: 1px;
```

Notice how the width of the first column changed from 199px to 200px, but the absolute left position of the second column stayed the same? The second column is hiding the border of the first column.

Is this a known problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: What is your base theme?

Comment: are you facing it in chrome only or another browser too ?